# Eclipse fails to start on Windows if -Xmx option is specified a higher value

Tags: eclipse, startup

I'm running inside a VM. In the VMWare settings, I can see that the RAM alloted is 6016 MB which is 6GB.
As recommended in our company I used -Xmx1024m (the default was 512) but eclipse fails to start, saying jvm exit code -1. The maximum value for Xmx that works is 660m. Why is this happening? Please help before I shoot myself.

Edit: I'm able to run a Helloworld java program specifying the option -Xmx1024m. Only eclipse cribs during starting.

Comment: If you're running on Linux, what does `free -m` on the command line show?

Comment: No, I'm running on Windows 2003 VM.

Comment: Did you eventually find the answer? I've seen this elsewhere with another Java app. Lots of RAM but putting -Xmx1024 failed where putting -Xmx800m worked. Makes no sense to me...

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that your OS and JVM are both 64-bit. In a 32-bit environment virtual memory address space fragmentation can result in relatively small contiguous memory blocks being available.

If you have to stay with 32-bit OS, then try adding the following to the start of your eclipse.ini file:

```
-vm
[some.path]/javaw.exe
```

You may also want to try disabling any devices that aren't strictly required as that will load fewer drivers into the address space and cause less fragmentation.

Comment: It is a 32 bit VM created on a 64 bit machine. In the VM I ofcourse have 32 bit JVM. So the problem you talk about should not be there.

Comment: If your VM is 32-bit, then it is useless to assign 6GB to it. A 32-bit OS can only see 4GB. In 32-bit address space, Java has well documented problems allocating large contiguous memory blocks, which is the problem you are running into. Even though your address space is 4GB, drivers and other DLLs pin into memory in various fixed locations fragmenting the address space. Different system will have different max contiguous block. The best solution is to get yourself a 64 bit VM, etc.

Comment: I see. But we only do development on 32 bit system. Are you aware of any solution to the address fragmentation problem in the 32 bit VM? Any tools etc.

Comment: There are some hacking techniques to re-home drivers and DLLs. I do not know the details. They aren't something that anyone not already familiar with low-level OS memory allocation should undertake. You can try launching eclipse with javaw.exe instead of default jvm.dll. That gets one DLL out of the way, which may help a bit. I will update the answer.

Comment: Also I have a few doubts. Why would there be fragmentation unless there are lots of other programs running, which I don't have. Also I'm able to run a simple java program with the option -Xmx1024m. Only Eclipse cribs if I specify this value.

Comment: Programs aren't the cause of fragmentation. The issue are drivers and DLLs. By default Eclipse launcher uses jvm.dll. You may get better results by forcing it to use javaw.exe. See my updated issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try running with parameters   -Xms1024M -Xmx6016M

Here Xms is the initial heap memory at startup and xmx is total heap memory that can be allocated. You can increase or decrease heap memory depending on your project and objects size.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with -Xmx1024m and -Xms512m. Somtimes if the difference between maximum and minimum heap space size is too large it affects eclipse startup.

Ok Now,
Remove all the Windows java files from the System32 directory and install the latest jdk from sun. Then start the Eclipse, it will run I hope.

After removing it may ask for the latest jdk/jre. So set the path to include jre in JDK. And run it.

Comment: try the modified answer and let me know

Comment: Prior to installing Eclipse I had downloaded the latest jdk, and during this installation only the java files had been copied to the system32 directory, as I can confirm from the timestamp of the files.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Android bundle version `- adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219`
I had the same issue with the virtual machine failing to start. I reduced the mem max (running in a VM as well xp x86). I found this thread and modified the config and it worked for me. The VM ram was 1.7gb, upped to 2.1 with no change.

I changed the eclipse.ini setting from 
`-Xmx768m`
to
`-Xmx512m`
and it started straight away.
I left the min at 40m and the other settings were unchanged.

Heres the full config:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Declipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685
```